# sam local invoke - Unable to import module 'app'

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I'm struggling for a few days with this issue and similar posts couldn't really help. So I'll giving it another try. I'm learning sam cli and how to test a lambda function locally before trying to deploy it to AWS Lambda. Thanks in advance for every support.

Here is my project structure, got it by `tree -L 2`:

```bash
    .
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── envs
    │   ├── dev.json
    │   └── prd.json
    ├── event.json
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── src
    │   ├── app.py
    │   └── utils.py
    └── template.yml
```

This is my **Dockerfile** content looks like this, just a small hint I'm passing an argument (either "dev" or "prd") and depending on that the environment variables saved in one of the json files is loaded:

```
    # Specify the base image
    FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11 AS build-stage
    
    # Install build dependencies for psutil (pyproject.toml)
    RUN yum install -y gcc python3-devel gcc-c++
    
    # Set the working directory inside the container
    WORKDIR /app
    
    # Copy requirements.txt from the root of your project
    COPY requirements.txt .
    
    # Install Python dependencies without plotly to a temporary directory
    RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
        pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt --target /tmp/python-deps
    
    # -------------------- Stage 2 --------------------
    # Build the final stage
    FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11 AS final-stage
    
    # Remove unnecessary dependencies (optional, but recommended)
    RUN yum remove -y gcc python3-devel gcc-c++ && \
        yum clean all
    
    # Copy the Python dependencies from the build-stage
    COPY --from=build-stage /tmp/python-deps /app
    
    # Copy source code
    COPY src /app/src
    
    # Argument to specify environment
    ARG ENVIRONMENT=dev
    ENV ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
    
    # Copy the appropriate environment file based on the argument
    COPY envs/${ENVIRONMENT}.json /app/.env
    
    # Set the entry point for the Lambda function
    CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
```

And this is my **template.yml** content:

```yaml
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
    Description: AWS SAM template for testing Docker-based Lambda function
    
    Parameters:
      Environment:
        Type: String
        Description: The environment (dev or prd)
        Default: dev
        AllowedValues: [dev, prd]
    
    Globals:
      Function:
        Timeout: 180
        MemorySize: 256
    
    Resources:
      DockerDemo:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
          CodeUri: src/
          PackageType: Image
           ImageConfig:
             Command: [app.lambda_handler]
          Environment:
            Variables:
              ENVIRONMENT: !Ref Environment
          ImageUri: !Sub docker-demo:${Environment}
        Metadata:
          DockerTag: !Ref Environment
          DockerContext: .
          Dockerfile: Dockerfile
          DockerBuildArgs:
            ENVIRONMENT: !Ref Environment
          DockerEnvFiles:
            - envs/${Environment}.json
```

My python script **app.py** is a very simple script, I'm a beginner:

```py
    # Importing our utils
    import json
    import utils
    
    def lambda_handler(event : dict, context : dict) -> dict:
        try:
            
            env_vars = utils.load_env()
            utils.load_mysql(env_vars = env_vars)
            
            return {
                'status' : 200,
                'message' : 'Everything worked nice!'
            }
            
        except Exception as e:
            return {
                'status' : 400,
                'message' : f'Something went wrong: \'{e}\''
            }
```

---

**The next step is to build, so I type in my terminal the following commands:**

1. `sam build --use-container`

```bash
    Build Succeeded
    
    Built Artifacts  : .aws-sam/build
    Built Template   : .aws-sam/build/template.yaml
    
    Commands you can use next
    =========================
    [*] Validate SAM template: sam validate
    [*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke
    [*] Test Function in the Cloud: sam sync --stack-name {{stack-name}} --watch
    [*] Deploy: sam deploy --guided
```

2. `sam local invoke DockerDemo --event event.json` and then I do get this error:

```bash
Invoking Container created from dockerdemo:dev                                                                                                                                                   
Local image was not found.                                                                                                                                                                       
Removing rapid images for repo dockerdemo                                                                                                                                                        
Building image..................
Using local image: dockerdemo:rapid-x86_64.                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                 
START RequestId: b110d6b1-81bd-4c13-9cfe-27692c1a37b5 Version: $LATEST
Traceback (most recent call last): Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'
END RequestId: b110d6b1-81bd-4c13-9cfe-27692c1a37b5
REPORT RequestId: b110d6b1-81bd-4c13-9cfe-27692c1a37b5  Init Duration: 1.02 ms  Duration: 435.02 ms     Billed Duration: 436 ms Memory Size: 256 MB     Max Memory Used: 256 MB
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "b110d6b1-81bd-4c13-9cfe-27692c1a37b5", "stackTrace": []}%
```

PS: I'm working on a MacBook Pro M2 (Apple Silicon Chip). I do not think that this is an issue, since I'm not getting any architecture issues.

Comment: By the way, I do have my project published on GitHub for more detailed purposes. Of course the environment variables are not available.

https://github.com/AbdoCherry/docker-sam-demo

Answer (score 1):

I could figure out where the issue relied on.

Rechecking my Dockerfile I had to know first, that if I use as Base Image the public offered image from AWS: `FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11` the folder structure where the code is executed is "var/task/" or `${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}`.

If I try to make a Working Directory like in my line here: `WORKDIR /app`, it wont lead to an error, but the docker container and the sam cli doesn't care, it tries to execute only the file set from the line `CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]`, but it cannot find that file because it does not exist in `var/task/`.

I hope this could help for developers who had a similar issue.

Best regards.